# Display defaultValue after ajax call using react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm using `react-select` package, and I'm unable to select a value by default after loading a list using Ajax call, this is my whole component :

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "../../custom/api/axios";
import Select from "react-select";

const UserForm = () => {
  const [managerList, setManagerList] = useState([]);
  const [formattedManagersList, setFormattedManagersList] = useState([]);
  const [selectIsLoading, setSelectIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [selectedManager, setSelectedManager] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    getManagers();
    // data loaded:
    // [
    //   { id: 1, displayName: "Test 1" },
    //   { id: 2, displayName: "Test 2" },
    //   { id: 3, displayName: "Test 3" },
    // ];
  }, []);

  const getManagers = async () => {
    setSelectIsLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(
        `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/managers`
      );
      const formattedList = response.data.data.map((item) => ({
        value: item.id,
        label: item.displayName,
      }));
      setManagerList(response.data.data);
      setFormattedManagersList(formattedList);
      setSelectedManager({ value: 3, label: "Test 3" });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    setSelectIsLoading(false);
  };

  return (
    <Select
      options={formattedManagersList}
      isLoading={selectIsLoading}
      placeholder="Select a Manager..."
      onChange={(item) => {
        setSelectedManager(managerList.find((m) => m.id === item.value));
      }}
      selectedValue={selectedManager}
    />
  );
};

export default UserForm;
```

I'm trying to manually select a `manager` after component load, by adding it to state using `setSelectedManager({ value: 3, label: "Manager Test" });` and then using the react-select `selectedValue` attribute `selectedValue={selectedManager}`, but nothing shows.

And the option `{ value: 3, label: "Test 3" }` does exist in the `formattedManagersList`, but not displayed and selected by default after the list is loaded.

And when I use value instead of selectedValue `value={selectedManager}`, the option shows in the select but when I click and change the selection, nothing appears as selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created and `stackblitz` link and fixed your issue in it.
I've removed `axios` and instead of it use `delay` function to simulate what you're request will take time. I handled loading time and finally, I've used value and defaultValue attributes at the same time.

I hope you find it useful.
[link to stackblitz example of your issue response.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-p2vtwh?file=src/Component.js)

Comment: I already fixed the issue but thanks for the reply, I just had to do `selectedManager && (<select...>)`. but it's pretty much the same approach as yours. Thanks.

Comment: You're so welcome.